# I am confused by this object required error VBA

Tags: vba, automation

I have been working on this VBA Code for a long time. The goal is to copy something from my excel document, search for it online, and then pull back something from the html code. I keep getting an error code that says "Object Required" and sometimes it says "Object variable or With block variable not set." It is all focused on the line "set elementTWO = elementONE.Item(i).innerText

I have tried deleting the word "Set" I have tried changing elementTWO to a string. Another really weird piece is the For...Next Loop won't let me do "exit for." It returns an error. I have tried a few other things to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub GetCategory()

Dim RowNo, ColNo, i As Integer
Dim Parent, Item, URL1, URL2, URL3 As String
Dim objHTML As Object
Dim elementONE As Object
Dim elementTWO As String


RowNo = 3
ColNo = 5

URL1 = "http://www.infores.com/public/us/knowledgegroup/resources/resources.pli?defaultDataType=&pageid=validatorresults&upc1="
URL2 = "&upc2="
URL3 = "&submitupc=find+it%21"

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    With Worksheets(1)
    While RowNo <= 5
        Parent = Cells(RowNo, ColNo)
        Item = Cells(RowNo, ColNo + 1)

        With ie
            .navigate URL1 & Parent & URL2 & Item & URL3
            .Visible = False

        'Delay while IE loads
        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            DoEvents
        Loop

            'Put html code in document object
            Set objHTML = .document
            DoEvents
        End With


        Set elementONE = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("TD") 'Break Down HTML code

            For i = 1 To elementONE.Length
                elementTWO = elementONE.Item(i).innerText
                If elementTWO = "Description" Then              'Find the Category
                    Cells(RowNo, ColNo + 4) = elementONE.Item(i + 1).innerText    'Put Category into excel
                End If
                Next i


            DoEvents
            ie.Quit
            RowNo = RowNo + 1
    Wend

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare all of your variables: `Dim objHTML, elementONE, elementTWO As Object`
Dims the first to as variants, then elementTwo as and Object, this is likely not what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I tried declaring all of my variables individually but I got the same result.

Comment: What is the type of elementONE.Item(i).innerText? is it an object? It appears as though it is a string. It seems like you want to Dim elementTWO as String, since you are comparing it to a string on the next line.

Comment: I agree, that makes sense. When I do that, though, I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: can you update your code above?

Comment: your problem is with elementONE you have declared it as an Object, then you are trying to access elementONE .Items and Object is a generic object it doesnt have an items collection.

Comment: What type of variable should it be to contain an items collection?

Comment: this is closer, but still not quite what you want,                 elementTWO = elementONE(i)
                If elementTWO = "Description" Then              'Find the Category
                    Cells(RowNo, ColNo + 4) = elementONE(i + 1)  'Put Category into excel
                End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this I think is what you want, it processes the loop but then fails during it. you can atleast debug it and see why:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub GetCategory()

Dim RowNo, ColNo, i As Integer
Dim Parent, Item, URL1, URL2, URL3 As String
Dim objHTML As Object, elementONE As Object, elementTWO As String


RowNo = 3
ColNo = 5

URL1 = "http://www.infores.com/public/us/knowledgegroup/resources/resources.pli?defaultDataType=&pageid=validatorresults&upc1="
URL2 = "&upc2="
URL3 = "&submitupc=find+it%21"

Dim ie As Object
'Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


With Worksheets(1)
    While RowNo <= 5
        Parent = Cells(RowNo, ColNo)
        Item = Cells(RowNo, ColNo + 1)

        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        With ie
            .navigate URL1 & Parent & URL2 & Item & URL3
            .Visible = False

        'Delay while IE loads
        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            DoEvents
        Loop

            'Put html code in document object
            Set objHTML = .document
            DoEvents
        End With


        Set elementONE = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("TD") 'Break Down HTML code

            For i = 0 To elementONE.Length - 1
                elementTWO = elementONE(i).innerText
                If elementTWO = "Description" Then              'Find the Category
                    Cells(RowNo, ColNo + 4) = elementONE(i + 1).innerText  'Put Category into excel
                End If
            Next i


            DoEvents
            ie.Quit
            RowNo = RowNo + 1
    Wend

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can only get it to return the first category. So if that is what you mean, it is working. This is my first program though and I don't really know much about debugging. How do I get this to run through as many times as needed? The error I am running into is "Object Variable or With block Variable not set"

Comment: I am really needing some help. Do you think you could look at this again? I have stared at this program for like 16 hours and cannot get past this error. I really appreciate the effort this far, but I'm still stuck!

Comment: one problem is the array is going out of bounds: update: For i = 0 To elementONE.Length - 1 then at least that part is taken card of. When i run this I get this page: http://www.infores.com/public/us/knowledgegroup/resources/resources.pli?defaultDataType=&pageid=validatorresults&upc1=&upc2=&submitupc=find+it%21
which is basically a no search results found page. There is no "description" to be found. perhaps on yours this will solve your issue, because you have the actual worksheet.

Comment: That worked, it is now running through the code one time, and then it breaks the second time through at the URL. The problem with running the URL for you is it is pulling data from the worksheet to put into the URL. You could try plugging in Parent = 98997 and Item = 80880. The URL works for me the first time though and not the second which I don't really understand.

Comment: See edit, re Set ie before the with block, and you should be in business.